# Blazor Architecture

Tags: structure, blazor

I am building a Blazor app and I have a need to reuse a bit of code that returns teh results of a linq query.  My question is where do i put general code? What is the accepted place in the structure?  I've got the following folders to choose from:

- Authentication
- Controllers
- Data
- Models
- Pages
- Services
- Shared

and then once i've got this how do i call this public method?  Is it enough that it is public or do i need to create a class variable of type x?  Pretty basic stuff but i'm stuck.

I've puyt the methoid in once page component/class anmd then to use it elsewhere I 've created a new new instance of the class component so i can reference the method but is this the best way?

thanks

John

Comment: I can reference the method but the dbcontext that i'm using in the source class is null so the query thows and exception.  How do i get the dbcontext instantiated?

Comment: Are you using server side or client (WebAssembly) Blazor?

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are reusing has html or css then use a .razor otherwise, use a .cs

Looking at your folder structure, MVC is not a good choice to architect Blazor apps as MVC is for Stateless and Blazor is not Stateless.  There are several choices on how to accomplish getting data into a component, my favorite is DI.

Comment: THis is the the structure automativcally created by the design app(Radzen) so i have no choice in the way they strucutre it.  My question is where in this do i put my general code?

Comment: I'm using server side